# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in program.exe

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic, unhandled-exception

**VB.NET: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in program.exe**

There are few more questions like this, but they didn't help at all. I'm working in VB.NET and I'm trying to add COM reference into project. I did it few years ago successfully and now it doesn't work. 
I have registered dll successfully, I have tried all things I read here, but I'm still getting error when I try to run program. I have changed platform from AnyCPU to x86, Working directory is set to be equal to the bin\debug directory and it still doesn't work.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports eVehicleRegistrationCOM

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim vd As New eVehicleRegistrationCOM.Registration

        Dim i As Integer
        i = vd.Initialize


    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is in this line:

```
Dim vd As New eVehicleRegistrationCOM.Registration
```

Here is the whole error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in program.exe

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0BE1D001-F522-44E7-B956-F1E8A52179E0} failed due to the following error: 8007007e.
```

Comment: Have you inspected the Registry entry of your COM object?. It may have dependencies located elsewhere. In an unreachable/Network path or a path subject to permissions missing in the current context.

Comment: I searched the web for that error code. Did you? For one thing, I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/612679/retrieving-the-com-class-factor). It's not perfectly written but it looks like it might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed dll, downloaded older version, registered it again, added into the project, and it works now perfectly!